# Chrome extension - Input value set in JS won't get submitted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set value of an input field that is on a webpage via Chrome extension. The value does get filled successfully, however when form is submitted, it gives error of input field being empty.

Input field code:

```
<input type="text" class="text-center CustomTextBox ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" autocomplete="off" min="0" maxlength="6" jcs-decimals="2" jcs-allow-null="false" jcs-decimals-hide-zero="true" ng-model="p.quantity" ng-disabled="p.OutOfStock" ng-blur="vm.QtyEntered(p)" ng-change="vm.qtyChanged(p)">
```

Javascript (inside inject.js of my chrome extension):

```
var foundinput = getElementsByTagName('input').item(0);
foundinput.value = 5.00;
```

Could it have anything to do with `ng-change` not getting triggered?

P.S. When value is entered manually, the form does submit successfully.

Comment: Where is `getElementsByTagName` defined?

Comment: @code  In the inject.js file of the chrome extension

Comment: Okay. Just wondering, what's the reason for setting the value of the input to `5.00` instead of `5`?

Comment: @code Because when I enter a non-decimal number manually in the input, it automatically adds two decimal points, so I am doing the same just to be safe. Just so you know, when I don't add decimals, the same problem is still there.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference. `5.00 === 5`.

Comment: @code Yes but its not working with 5 either.